# Stuck at Nuka World (2 issues)

Tags: fallout-4

I am stuck in Nuka World with 2 issues, I am not certain how to fix and/or progress.

Playing in Survival mode on PC, so no console commands available.

1. To collect the last Star Core, I need to have the power restored to access the elevator.
   How do I restore the power ? There are not quest assigned to it.
   I have installed all the Star Core (minus the last one) in the computer.
   I have finished all the park sections and assigned the same gang to all of them.
2. Expanding my gang foot-hold in the Commonwealth.
   Shank tells me I have to do jobs, but the location selection show 2 places, but I cannot select either of them.
   The Workshop is marked as a "quest location" but I am not certain what to build; I have already build the radio beacon, an amplifier and some other raider specific items; but I am not certain what to build more.

Thanks.

Max

edit:

I did not properly finished the nuka world quests in the Commonwealth, have settlements and make the gangs "happy" (I assigned one of them to food, so he was not happy at all).

One that was done, I got a notification to get back to Nuka World to finish up the quests.

Thanks.

Comment: To Point 2: Had you also tried to build a Raider Flag under the Raider Build Tab ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You restore power at the end of the [Power Play quest](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Play), which is the next quest after you set up the Raider outpost during the [Home Sweet Home quest](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Home_Sweet_Home) in the Commonwealth.

As Serverfrog said, you need to build the Raider-gang specific flagpole in the settlement to claim it after you have either killed the settlers or told them to leave. When you talk to Shank, you decide which gang you want to man the settlement you chose to take over. You then have to craft the flag that corresponds to the gang you selected.

In the crafting menu, all the way on the right is a "Raider" section. Within that section are the flags you need to craft and place. I believe it's 2 steel and 2 cloth per flag.

Comment: I believe the door to the power switch unlocks after you kill all the raiders, letting you restore power anyway.

Comment: This is true, though I didn't include that since it sounds the user is attempting to expand his influence in the Commonwealth

Comment: I've had all the nuka worl beacon, and chem station and amplifier en booze still; but I had 1 gang member assigned to food production which blocked the progression.

Comment: Interesting... I don't remember having a problem with that. I had one on the booze still, one on the chem station, and one on food and was able to advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can still restore power to the park (and elevator for the last star core) if you kill all the Raider leaders for the 'good' path (Open Season), where you don't raid the Commonwealth.

You just need to complete Power Play, which you can also do after completing the 'Open Season' quest, where you kill all three of the factions leaders, allowing you to restore power to the park.   Can save you a lot of time messing around with the Raider factions, just be forwarned that the raider boss battles are tough, and once you start those fights, every Raider in all of Nuka World will be gunning for you constantly, so be ready.